# How to make a simple login without a database and without a form

Tags: python, security, flask, flask-login

I want to add a simple login feature where one can either be logged in or not logged in (no user-specific data needs to be stored).

I made a User class:

```
class User(object):
def __init__(self, username, hash):
    self.name = username
    self.hash = hash
```

and I load a list of users from an INI file.

I implemented the user_loader function

```
@self.login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(userid):
        for user in self.users:
            if user.name == userid
                return user
        return None
```

What goes in the login method?

```
@self.server.route("api/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
        def login():
```

I want to do the login with an ajax request where I send the credentials and get a JSON response that contains the username or an error message.

Answer (score 2):

Simple example, which will work with `POST /api/login` with `username=TEST_USER&hash=TEST_HASH` data or `GET /api/login?username=TEST_USER&hash=TEST_HASH`:

```
class User(UserMixin):

    def __init__(self, username, hash):
        self.name = username
        self.hash = hash

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.name


@self.server.route('/api/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    user = load_user(request.values.get('username'))
    if user and user.hash == request.values.get('hash'):
        login_user(user)
        return jsonify(status='ok', username=user.username)
    else:
        return jsonify(status='error', message='wrong username or hash')
```

However I prefer only POST http method for login.

Really your own implementation will be dependent from your js call, for example you can use `request.get_json` instead POST `request.form` or GET `request.args`. And login algorithm (credentials fields).

Also `load_user` can be slow with big amount of `users`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But `current_user.is_authenticated()` still returns false in all functions except the login function. How can I access the user?

Comment: Do you have `user_id` in session after login?

Comment: Only inside the login function. Everywhere else it throws a KeyError.

Comment: If you use default session storing in cookies then maybe your cookies disabled.

Comment: I didn't change anything on the flask server and my browser allows cookies.

Comment: Maybe you have several ajax requests at one time with login that can override cookies. However it's hard to help more without additional information.

Comment: Yes, I have an ajax request running at any time. Is there a way around it? I can also post my code if you want.

Comment: I mean race condition when you send **several** ajax requests at **one time**: first request set cookie, but second can override cookie.

Comment: I do one ajax request that asks if something on the server has changed. It will run for up to ten seconds. If the user has logged in, the original status request will be answered and returns no user logged in. But when the client website does another status request, the user is still not logged in.